# Is it possible to get Network Domain from Client with PHP or Apache?

Tags: network, php, access-control, apache, domain

I'm working on a solution to identify client Network Domain or Workgroup in a private network. Based on it, I must change some access permissions.

I can't do that through IP address because it isn't trustable, only network domain/ workgroup.

For reasons unknown to me I can't have a login screen, access must be automatic and seamless.

Someone know how can I do it?

Sorry to post it here, follow it on the correct place: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31349047/3706998

Comment: You want to be able to access the computer's local network domain info from a web session? I'm afraid web is a few layers above the network domain level.

Comment: Yes! Thats the problem, I know php works on Session Layer but there is a many functions of network.
May a Apache config could request this information from client.

Comment: The short answer is "no". Unless you had some function that could read the OS-level details of the client (like `phpinfo` on the server side) you cannot see this data.

Comment: The PHP function [gethostbyaddr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php) is enought to return domain machine name inside a private network.. I just must know the Remote Address (IP)

Comment: gethostbyaddr will return the *public* domain, not the private one

Comment: Are the clients under a private network "public" ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's possible to get corresponding to a given IP address using `gethostbyaddr` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php:

```
    $proxy = (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : false;

if(!!$proxy){
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
     echo "Warning: Your cliend is using proxy, may could not determine hostname";
    }else{
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; //
    }
    $hostname = gethostbyaddr($ipaddress); //Its will return domain + machine-name inside a private network.

    if($ipaddress  == $hostname){
     echo "Impossible to determine hostname for: ", $ipaddress ;
    }else{
      echo "The hostname for ", $ipaddress, "is : ",  $hostname;
    }
```

But the communication using application / session layer to network layer is a little complicated. You must don't trust it to access control in php applications.

Comment: If you are outside the network, you will not be able to know the internal domain name because you are getting the external IP address. `gethostbyaddr` uses DNS.

Comment: You're right! If you are on Internet or in a different network the reverse IP will be gotten.(code bellow [here](http://www.leonancarvalho.com/projects/info.php))
But if your server and client is in a private network your machine name will be gotten.
The server must be able to request this remote IP using lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Not really. You can directly retrieve some agent information and the local IP/hostname but not their workgroup/domain status.

That being said - you could get the hostname and query Active Directory via WMI to see if it is a domain computer, but you can never prove the validity of the hostname.

Another option is that you can authenticate a user against Active Directory/LDAP. You could have a login page that when they authenticate against Active Directory (proving they are a domain user) you let them login.

Also have a look at [Authenticating in PHP using LDAP through Active Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171519/authenticating-in-php-using-ldap-through-active-directory).

Comment: Assuming the webserver has access to the local network. If the webserver has access to the local network, then they already know the domain.

Comment: For reasons unknown to me I can not have a login screen, access needs to be automatic and seamless.
The only thing I need is domain name to show data from "A" or "B" based on sub-domain name.

Eg.

domain.global.machine-name: Show global data
domain.localA.machine-name: Show localA data

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

You can create a landing page that lists all client IP addresses using [WebRTC](https://github.com/diafygi/webrtc-ips) and load another address.

You can use `gethostbyaddr()` on every IP returned, and you will get some `user198.domain-a.company.xxx`. Just set a session variable, and you are set.

Comment: WebRTC is cool, but doesn't work on IE !

Comment: Yes, it does. Not out of the box, but with the help of a couple plugins: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc4all/ or https://temasys.atlassian.net/wiki/display/TWPP/WebRTC+Plugins or https://github.com/sarandogou/webrtc-everywhere